# why is switch-to-buffer effect not visible immediately when called in a list with other functions?

Tags: buffers, elisp-macros

I have a key bound to some program which prepares a buffer, switches to it via `switch-to-buffer` and afterwards calls some function which modifies the buffer (and can take a few seconds to execute).

When pressing the key, this modifying function is executed **before** the buffer is actually switched (noticeable by a considerable lag), although it appears **after** `switch-to-buffer`.

Can somebody please explain why this is the case?

Here are full details, although I don't think these are relevant for my problem:

I'm using elfeed and have set `elfeed-entry-switch`, which by default is just `#'switch-to-buffer`, to `#'my-elfeed-entry-switch`, where

```lisp
(defun my-elfeed-entry-switch (buffer)
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (switch-to-buffer buffer)
      (org-latex-preview)))
```

The computationally intensive function therefore is `org-latex-preview`, which renders and displays inline latex code and, like I wrote, sometimes takes several seconds to complete.

When trying to switch to an entry which contains a lot of latex code, I have to wait for a second or so before the buffer becomes visible.

What I actually expect is that the buffer first becomes visible (with unrendered latex code) and then `org-latex-preview` starts its work, which it does if called interactively.

**UPDATE** As suggested below, removing `with-current-buffer` does not solve the problem, i.e.

```lisp
(defun my-elfeed-entry-switch (buffer)
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    (org-latex-preview))
```

still does not show the buffer before `org-latex-preview` has finished rendering.

Comment: Please do not use tag `elisp` for questions about using Elisp. It's for questions about the nature of the language itself compared to other languages, in particular, compared to other Lisp dialects.

Comment: A redisplay can be forced at a particular location with `(sit-for 0)` or `(redisplay t)` ....

Comment: @lawlist Thank you very much, inserting  `(redisplay t)` after `(switch-to-buffer buffer)` solves my problem. Do you care to write your comment as an answer or shall I do it myself?

Comment: Redisplays happens whenever emacs waits for new input, that's why buffer swtiching seems to happen *after* `org-latex-preview` execution, but isn't. Only redisplaying happens once your function returns. Still, `with-current-buffer` doesn't make sense in your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The O.P. has indicated in a comment that inserting `(redisplay t)` following the `switch-to-buffer` call resolves the issue outlined in the question.  Another idea would be to use `(sit-for 0)`, which also forces a redisplay by the display engine.  The function `redisplay` contains a doc-string that states:

```
redisplay is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(redisplay &optional FORCE)

Perform redisplay.

Optional arg FORCE, if non-nil, prevents redisplay from being
preempted by arriving input, even if ‘redisplay-dont-pause’ is nil.
If ‘redisplay-dont-pause’ is non-nil (the default), redisplay is never
preempted by arriving input, so FORCE does nothing.

Return t if redisplay was performed, nil if redisplay was preempted
immediately by pending input.
```